# TypeError: items.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, react

Fiz uma requisição em uma URL via Fetch, todavia ele me retorna um erro quando peço o mapeamento do json, alguem sabe como resolver ?

**Ocultei a URL pois é privada.**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class App extends Component {
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {
 items:[],
 isLoaded: false,
 }
 }

componentDidMount(){
fetch('***')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => { 
    this.setState({
      isLoaded: true,
      items : json,
    })
  });
 }

render() {

var{isLoaded, items} = this.state;

if(!isLoaded){
  return <div>Loading..</div>
}
else{

return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => (
          <li key = {item.id}>
            Name : {item.name} | {item.name}
          </li>
        ))};
      </ul>    
    </div>
  );
 }
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Aparentemente ele não reconhece items como um array

Comment: No retorno da sua chamada ".then(res => res.json()) ", experimenta colocar um console.log() e verificar oque está retornando da api pois como o Lucas Brogni citou pode ser que a api não esteja retornando um array ....

Answer (score 3):

A primeira coisa que você deve fazer é dar um `console.log(res.json())` para saber o que está vindo nesta requisição. O `.map` só  será executado caso seja um array, se estiver vindo algo nesse **res.json()** use o comando `typeof` para verificar o tipo. Certamente o que está passando para essa response não é um array, ou não está passando nada.